# list connected to database dont show the data JSP

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

My page dont show the data in a option list,the data input is from a table in a data base, appears the number of registers but in white dont appears the data. i want to select a option from the list....

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@page language="java"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
    <body>
        <table id="cliente" border="1" class="tabla">
            <form  method="get" action="generaReporte" id="forminicio">
            <tr><th class="thCliente">Febrero</th></tr>
            <th class="thCliente">Fecha </th>
            <th class="thCliente">Cliente</th>
            <th class="thCliente">Actividad</th>
            <th class="thCliente">Horas</th>

 <th>    
            <%//establecemos la conexion a la BD para mostrar los clientes
            try
            {
                Connection conexion = null; 
                Statement sentencia = null;
                ResultSet resultado = null;
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                String cadenaConexion = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/LOGIN";
                String usuario = "root";
                String clave = "5533834712";
                conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(cadenaConexion,usuario,clave);
                if(!conexion.isClosed())
                {
                    sentencia = conexion.createStatement();
                    resultado = sentencia.executeQuery("select * from cliente");
                    out.println("<select style='width:300px;border:1px;font-family:sans-serif;font-size: 16px;' name='select'>");
                    out.println("<option >Selecciona el Cliente</option>");
                    while(resultado.next())
                    {
                     String nombre = resultado.getString("Nombre");
                     //String id = resultado.getString("id");
                     out.println("<option value='"+nombre+"'></option>");
                    }
                    out.println("</select>");
                    conexion.close();
                }
                else
                    out.println("fallo");
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                out.println("Error"+e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            %>
    </th>
</tr>
            </form>
        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use  something like this should work.

```
<option value='"+nombre+"'> nombre </option>
```

Comment: Yes! it works but i use <option value='"+nombre+"'>"+nombre+"</option>  Thank´s!